# Redis cache doesn't update sometimes with frequent updates

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

Let me explain the architecture,

Basically, this is a system that displays car racing stats built with Laravel. There are two entities in my system, races, and drivers that are related to this issue.

These are the data processing steps,

1. I get to race and driver updates from external APIs
2. Normalise these incoming data
3. Store updates in the DB
4. Cache the same updates in the Redis cache

I receive detailed updates every second.

The issue is sometimes the Redis cache does not update as expected and due to this frontend displays older data. So I have to manually clear the cache for that specific race or driver.

My questions are,

1. Can this be happened because of high-frequency cache updates?
2. If so what are the best practices I can use to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Without some minimal code that reproduces this issue we can't really know what the problem might be. Also more details on your cache architecture would help e.g. is it a cluster or single instance?

Comment: I use a single instance

Comment: How are you getting API updates every second? Background process? How do you ensure that there's no overlap between updates and each update is processed in the correct order? Do you update multiple rows and multiple cache entries per second or is it just a dump of all (normalized) data you get?

Comment: These external service pushes data for the system. I use laravel queues with beanstalkd to process data in the order they come. I update the cache with the entire race entity. this includes all the drivers as well.

Comment: Are you using a single queue worker?

Comment: Yes. One supervisor worker

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem might be. For example it could be that a job fails and then it's retried after X seconds and in the meantime other jobs are processed and then when the old job is retried it overwrites new data with old data or simply that some cache operations just fail silently. You assume this is an architecture issue (at least I think you do since you don't seem to think your code is relevant to this question) but this may not be the case as well